# Unity Sprite Editor Slice Results in Diamond Shaped Slices/Missing Data

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, game-engine, game-development, sprite-sheet

I am trying to slice a sprite sheet in Unity 2021.3.1. I have a 1024x1024 png I am saving 32x32 tile map sprites onto.

When I slice them they appear to be selected correctly.
[image: Example]

But each sprite ends up losing data and being in a diamond shape.
[image: Example]

Here are my settings for the Sprite Sheet.
[image: Settings]

I've tried adjusting the pixels per unit, manually defining each sprite, different slice options. I can't seem to find this issue online either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: If this is a software question, you are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question** and you must tag it with the programming language you are using along with any framework. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running into this as well. Ticking "Keep Empty Rects", slicing, unticking, and slicing again fixed it for me.